# SqlBulkCopy not working, no errors

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, datatable, sqlbulkcopy

I'm reading data from an Excel file or CSV. I take that data and create a datatable. I then merge that datatable with the datatable created from the original database. The merge works and I have already sorted out all of the datatypes and column names. I have a ton of links, but most of them boil down to datatype and column name/column text case.

No errors. Everything runs smoothly. The datatable I'm trying to bulk copy is correct in the VS table viewer. When I check in SQLExpress no changes have been made. I am using the same connection string that I have been for the rest of the project which works (row delete, add, edit, etc).

```vb
dt.Merge(dtnew)

    Using destinationConnection As SqlConnection = _
                   New SqlConnection(sConnectionString)
        destinationConnection.Open()

        ' Set up the bulk copy object.  
        ' The column positions in the source data reader  
        ' match the column positions in the destination table,  
        ' so there is no need to map columns. 

        Using bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = _
          New SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection)
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = _
            "dbo.TableName"

            Try
                ' Write from the source to the destination.
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt)

            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)

            Finally
                ' Close the SqlDataReader. The SqlBulkCopy 
                ' object is automatically closed at the end 
                ' of the Using block.
            End Try
        End Using

    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do the column mapping also..

```
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("source column name,"destination column name" )
```

or if you have same column name in dt and dbo.Tablename then you can use following code

```
For Each clmn As DataColumn In dt.Columns
     bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(clmn.ColumnName, clmn.ColumnName)
Next
```

Comment: I hope this works. One of the last couple of hurdles in this project... so far. Where does this go? I have identical column names, or at least I intend to.

Comment: column names as well as their datatypes should be identical.. I wonder why you are not getting any error... have used Try Catch block to catch the error?

Comment: Darn. There was an error, but I hadn't made a msgbox to display it. It is complaining about the column mappings. I'll give you the "answer" certification if this fixes it. Thanks.

Comment: I had a similar situation. There is no error because Exception is not being caught. The data set and destination table have exact same number of rows and same sequence of rows. Adding columns mapping still did not help. Just realized that there was a Task Scheduler job which is frequently truncating my tables. The moment SqlBulkCopy successfully wrote the data, it was truncated by Task Scheduler job. Disabling that job helped me.